# "#button_1" isn't affected by .click() or .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Probably a rookie mistake, but my `#button_1` ID isn't affected by the `click()` or `hover()` jQuery effects.

If someone could take a quick look at [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2haz/), it would be greatly appreciated.

It's probably pretty obvious, but I want `#button_1` to act as every other button. :)

Again, I suspect it's a pretty stupid mistake, something that I've overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat so much code , try this and its working

Try line by line , its throwing error in somewhere in the code and breaking the bind events.
you have some error in hover or so , remove everything and have bind events, they are work.

You know this right ,when line 1 breaks in documentready , all bindings below may not get binded.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

   $('#button_1,#button_2').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');

   });

});
```

Comment: Got it fixed man thanks, was real simple, just didn't realize that you could comma separate individual id's.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest condensing that code a little, to something closer to:

```
$('a div[class^="button"]').click(
    function(e){
        e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the click bubbling to the parent 'a' element
        $('.button_active')
            .removeClass('button_active')
            .addClass('button_normal');
        $(this).addClass('button_active').removeClass('button_normal');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y2haz/2/).

---

**Edited** in response to question from the OP:

> Just to add, [[the Fiddle updated by the OP to include the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/y2haz/5/)] actually sets "button_hover" as the class instead of "button_active", any idea why that would be?

Yep; that's in response to the specificity of the CSS selectors, I add and remove classes as needed in response events (rather than repeatedly checking for whether or not `button_hover` is set). As the element ends up with `class="button_normal button_hover"`, and the order of the css (I think) places greater emphasis on the later-declared class, `button_hover` is maintained. It's late, and I'm a bit tired, but that's sort of (in a nutshell) what's happening.

The following demo incorporates everything (I think) that you need, and, coupled with revised CSS selectors, should do as you want:

```
$('a div[class^="button"]').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('button_hover').click(
            function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.button_active')
                    .addClass('button_normal')
                    .removeClass('button_active');
                $(this).addClass('button_active').removeClass('button_hover');
            });
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('button_hover');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.button_active,
.button_normal.button_active { background: #000; }
.button_normal.button_hover { background: #ff0; }
.button_normal { background: #d89; }
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/y2haz/6/).

---

References:

- [attribute-begins-with (`^=`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`e.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for that :). So, just to clarify to make sure I'm on track, this binds a click event to the class of "button+wildcard", then removes the class "button_active" and adds "button_normal" for any elements with the class "button_active", and adds "button_active" to the clicked class?

Comment: Just to add, this actually sets "button_hover" as the class instead of "button_active", any idea why that would be? http://jsfiddle.net/y2haz/5/